# can not call function in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

Having problem call my function in stored procedure.

Below I created a function: `makePoint`. I want to use this in a stored procedure

`select * from my_table where dbo.makePoint(lon, lat).STWithin(my polygon)`

But I can not use the function.

The error message:

> the function is can not find the user defined function "makePoint".

What am I missing? I have created the SP and function in dbo.

```
-- ================================================
-- Template generated from Template Explorer using:
-- Create Inline Function (New Menu).SQL
--
-- Use the Specify Values for Template Parameters 
-- command (Ctrl-Shift-M) to fill in the parameter 
-- values below.
--
-- This block of comments will not be included in
-- the definition of the function.
-- ================================================
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.makePoint(@lon FLOAT, @lat FLOAT)  
RETURNS Geometry   
AS   
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @g Geometry   
    SET @g = Geometry::Point(@lon, @lat, 4326)  

    RETURN @g
END
GO
```

and my stored procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spGetItemsInRegion @regionId INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    declare @geo as Geometry
    select @geo = polygon from something where id = @regionId

    select * from my_table where dbo.makePoint(lon, lat).STWithin(@geo)    
END
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

[STWithin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stwithin-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) returns 0 or 1, and as a result you need to compare the function result to one of those values.

(Note that 1 and 0 do not behave as booleans in T-SQL)

Modified code:

```
select * from my_table
where dbo.makePoint(lon, lat).STWithin(@geo) = 1
```

Other than that the code should just work, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ffba3603a7a37d48e9d6f3fafec9c174).

Answer (score 0):

please check your where condition this should be like below

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE someting= dbo.makePoint(lon, lat).STWithin(@geo);
```